# Add private chat as a feature to a Parse based application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform, chat

I'm currently working on an application already created and given to me and they have asked me to implement a private chat function to the application.

I have not been able to find any helpful Parse tutorials out on the internet about making a private chat feature. So i'm coming here to ask you guys for some information.

UPDATE: I found out that my issue is the query. One of the query clauses is overwriting another and is not returning the rows i'm asking for based off of my two columns that are pointers and store PFUser objects. How can I modify my query to return what I need?

Here's a snippet of my query so far:

```
let recipient = PFQuery(className: "replies")
                recipient.whereKey("recipient", equalTo: (objs?.first)!)

                let sender = PFQuery(className: "replies")
                sender.whereKey("sender", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

                let replyQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([recipient, sender])

                replyQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [PFObject]?, err) in
                    if err == nil {
                        print(objects)
                    } else {
                        print(err)
                    }
                })
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Private chat feature, if decided to build on yourself, it means that the client and the server all should be build for the task. So are your team prepared for that, or just use the third party SDK to achieve the goal?

Comment: First, I do not recommend any new development using Parse. It has been slated for decommissioning by end of year. Also, that's a very broad question not suitable for this forum.

Comment: @childrenOurFuture all of the other features are functioning. I need help building a model to handle the private chat. My current model isn't working in the way I thought it would. I also need help writing a query to get the chat between only two people.

Comment: @picciano It's a deprecated back end yes, but I need to use it until we migrate our application. How can I less broaden the question? I need help building the model for the feature and writing the correct query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the most basic level (and minding my comments above) you could create message table containing the columns sender, recipient, date, message, and readFlag. Sender and recipient would be pointers to User objects. You could add a afterSave event to this table to send a push notification to the recipient. When the recipient reads the message, set the readFlag to true so that you can show the recipient their unread messages.

For the new messages query, the recipient could query on all messages where recipient = self, readFlag = false, and ordered by date.

Comment: You're awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm still not getting the results I want from this one post. What can I do to make a chat only one to one? Your method somewhat works but I see everyone typing in the chat field not just two people. I can post a snippet on here of my query if you'd like? I would be very grateful for some query creation help.

Comment: Also does self = PFUser.currentUser() ?